# Playing song list with jquery and html5 audio

Tags: jquery, html, audio, html5-audio

I'm trying to make html5 audio player to play list of songs but it plays only two first ones and stops there.

I'm using this to make it play next song after one ends:

```
$(audio).on("ended", function() {
audio.pause();
var next = $('#playlist li.active').next();
if (next.length == 0) {
    next = $('#playlist li:first-child');
}
initAudio(next);
audio.play();
showDuration();
});
```

Can't find out what is the problem here.

EDIT

Whole code:

JS

```
var audio;

$('#pause').hide();

initAudio($('#playlist li:first-child'));

function initAudio(element){
var song = element.attr('song');
var title = element.attr('songtitle');
var artist = element.attr('artist');

audio = new Audio('audio/' + song);

if(!audio.currentTime){
    $('#duration').html('0:00');
}

$('#audio-player .title').text(title);
$('#audio-player .artist').text(artist);

$('#playlist li').removeClass('active');
element.addClass('active');
}

$('#play').click(function(){
audio.play();
$('#play').hide();
$('#pause').show();
showDuration();
});

$('#pause').click(function(){
audio.pause();
$('#pause').hide();
$('#play').show();
});

$(audio).on("ended", function() {
audio.pause();
var next = $('#playlist li.active').next();
if (next.length == 0) {
    next = $('#playlist li:first-child');
}
initAudio(next);
audio.play();
showDuration();
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="audio-player">
    <button id="play"></button>
    <button id="pause"></button>
    <ul id="playlist">
        <li song="song1.wav" songtitle="Song1" artist="Artist1"></li>
        <li song="song2.wav" songtitle="Song2" artist="Artist2"></li>
        <li song="song3.wav" songtitle="Song3" artist="Artist3"></li>
        <li song="song4.wav" songtitle="Song4" artist="Artist4"></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="audio-info">
    <span class="artist"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="title"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move this code:

```
$(audio).on("ended", function() {
audio.pause();
var next = $('#playlist li.active').next();
if (next.length == 0) {
    next = $('#playlist li:first-child');
}
initAudio(next);
audio.play();
showDuration();
});
```

inside the `initAudio` function, like this:

```
function initAudio(element){
    var song = element.attr('song');
    var title = element.attr('songtitle');
    var artist = element.attr('artist');

    audio = new Audio('audio/' + song);

    if(!audio.currentTime){
        $('#duration').html('0:00');
    }

    $('#audio-player .title').text(title);
    $('#audio-player .artist').text(artist);

    $('#playlist li').removeClass('active');
    element.addClass('active');

    $(audio).on("ended", function() {
        audio.pause();
        var next = $('#playlist li.active').next();
        if (next.length == 0) {
            next = $('#playlist li:first-child');
        }
        initAudio(next);
        audio.play();
        showDuration();
    });
}
```

This will ensure the `ended` call will be triggered for all the `audio` elements, not only for the first one.

Currently, the `ended` event is only fired once. So, the code plays the first song, triggers the `ended` event, plays the second one and then doesn’t trigger `ended` anymore.

This is because `$(audio)` refers to the audio element that is destroyed and re-created when you do `initAudio`. The line:

```
audio = new Audio('audio/' + song);
```

creates a new `audio` element when you call initAudio. This new `audio` element will **not** have the same callback attached to it.

`$(audio).on("ended", ...);` is only attached one time, and if the code creates new elements of the same type, it won’t be re-attached to them. So, you need to re-attach your event callback each time the audio element is re-created, and this can be done in `initAudio`. If you used selectors, a common method is to use `$(document).on("ended", selector, ...);` for this, but it won’t work in your example, since `audio` is not a selector.

Comment: I added whole js and html in my question. $(document).on("ended", audio, ...); didn't work.

Comment: The code explains a lot! I’ve updated my answer, hopefully this should help.